# Is there a way to use an image from the =IMAGE() function as an image src in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a formula that fetches an image from a website and attaches a hyperlink to it:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.monstercat.com/release/"&Albums!J2,IMAGE(WIU!C7,4,195,195))
```

The image fetched is embedded in the range C10:C12.

Is there a way using the Google Sheets API to use this image (the image itself doesn't link to the URL of the image) as the src in JQuery?

JQuery code:

```
var result = $('body > .target-image').attr('src','`*[Spreadsheet Image]*`');
```

***Resources I am using:***

- Google Apps Script with Google Sheets API/JavaScript
- Color Thief (JS Library for extracting color from images)
- JQuery
- [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfbszPNxeeRkIGzB8xF1woSR4xJRut6j2-HDr1sGN20/edit#gid=569426832)

Comment: WIU!C7 has the image link. Right? Why not use that url instead?

Comment: I haven't figured out a way to get this link.  I can't find the link it leads to.

Comment: The link is in ``WIU!C7``

Comment: @TheMaster That's what I'm saying, I can't find `WIU!C7`.  Any idea where I can find it?

Comment: `WIU` is the sheet name. C7 is the cell with the link in that sheet. The sheet is hidden, if you can't find it. Search how to unhide a sheet.

Comment: Oh okay.  This is a collaboratory spreadsheet and I'm not the one who made the image fetching formula, didn't know he had hidden sheets.

Comment: @TheMaster that solves my issue, can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it and give you reputation?

Comment: The Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service and the Google Sheets API are two different things. The Sheets API could be used without using Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IMAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333) formula syntax is

```
=IMAGE(image url link,...)
```

In your case, the link is present in `WIU!C7`. You can directly use the link in the formula as your `image src`